# What's a word for describing a movie or a book that consume a lot of brain energy to understand?

Tags: word-request

Due to the complicated plots, you may consume a lot of brain energy to understand it.

In Chinese we call it "burning brain".

> What's burning brain movie! I watched it 3 times for fully
>   understanding it.

Comment: A difficult plot or text can be said to be: confusing, convoluted, taxing, a struggle to follow/understand, difficult to follow etc.

Comment: We might call it a *brain-teaser" or a *Chinese puzzle*. 'Brain-teaser' is more commonly used, though 'Chinese puzzle' - referring to puzzles like Tangram, where you move the shapes around to try and fit them together - might be a more accurate description. We might also call the plot 'dense' or 'convoluted'.